# Why is my process staying alive after app crash?

Tags: android, security, process, hardening

I have an application which I make crash at a certain point by deliberately throwing a `RuntimeException`. The result is that the app crashes, all visible traces of the activity disappear and the user is shown a popup dialog:

> *App* has stopped
>   [X] Close app

So far so good, all of this is to be expected.

However, I was able to observe on by calling `adb shell ps | grep <packageName>` before and after the crash that my process actually **survives** this crash. (The process is only killed once the user hits 'Close app'.)

- What are the implications of this process staying alive? In what state is this process? What resources does it need, and what information is still kept in memory?

*PS. I know of different possibilities to force app termination without the process surviving (e.g. `System.exit()` or `android.os.Process.killProcess()`) but this isn't the question - I'm really more interested in why the process is surviving an app crash.*

---

***Background** of my question is **application hardening** and root/tamper/debugger detection. In some of those cases, from a security/hardening perspective (i.e. making reverse engineering harder for potential attackers) it can be desirable to kill the app as quickly and cleanly as possible. I am totally aware that Android is not designed to give this kind of control to applications, and that you shouldn't normally try to terminate an app.*

Answer (score 2):

The reason Android keeps process alive for some time after crash is right the opposite to your goal :) it needs to gather some debug information and make it available for the app creator.

You can kill your process directly from code:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```